# jQuery slideup callback function syntax

Tags: jquery

I have the following jQuery which slides a div up, adds content and then slides back down. It works but the html is being applied before the slideup is complete so it looks a little off. I know I need to use the callback function but it breaks when I try. Being new to jquery I think I have some syntax wrong of I am referencing something incorrectly within the callback function somewhere if someone can spot it.

This is what I currently have:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.accordionContent').hide();

    $(".accordionButton").click(function () {

        var content_id = $(this).attr('href');

        $(this).nextAll('.active:first').slideUp('normal');

        $(this).nextAll('.active:first').html($(content_id).html()).slideDown('normal');

        return false;
    });
});
```

and this is what I have tried..

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.accordionContent').hide();

    $(".accordionButton").click(function () {

        var content_id = $(this).attr('href');

        $(this).nextAll('.active:first').slideUp('normal', function() {

        $(this).nextAll('.active:first').html($(content_id).html()).slideDown('normal');

        return false;

        });
    });
});
```

Comment: It breaks because you added `return false` in the callback, and it's in another scope, so `this` is no longer your element ?

Comment: Ok I think I see what you mean. It should be returning false to the original click function and not to the callback function. Do I just need to move it out?